# MinMaxScaler in Scikit Learn seems to be returning scaled values not belonging to the range of values specified by the `feature_range` parameter

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This is the example from official: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
>>>
>>> data = [[-1, 2], [-0.5, 6], [0, 10], [1, 18]]
>>> scaler = MinMaxScaler()
>>> print(scaler.fit(data))
MinMaxScaler(copy=True, feature_range=(0, 1))
>>> print(scaler.data_max_)
[  1.  18.]
>>> print(scaler.transform(data))
[[ 0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.25  0.25]
 [ 0.5   0.5 ]
 [ 1.    1.  ]]
>>> print(scaler.transform([[2, 2]]))
[[ 1.5  0. ]]
```

The official document is as below.

> transform(X)[source] Scaling features of X according to feature_range.
>
> Parameters:    X : array-like, shape [n_samples, n_features]
>
> Input data that will be transformed.

Why am I seeing `[[ 1.5  0. ]]` as an output when the default value for `feature_range` parameter is `(0, 1)`?

Comment: The scaler was fitted by "data". When a given value is higher than the maximum value of the fitted data, the scaled value will be > 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the transform operation like this:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array(data)
f1 = data[:,0]
mn = f1.min()
mx = f1.max()
(f1- mn)/ (mx - mn)
```

note: the transform operation is constructed from your initial data. once the tranform operation is constructed, it will operate on your secondary data and does not re-scale it again. 
you may have problem with parameter feature_range. In that case you should know that after minmaxtransform it rescale the data.